# Загрузка файла на сервер RxAlamofire

Tags: swift

Пытаюсь сделать загрузку файла через RxAlamofire, но XCode выдает ошибку `Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`. Как ее исправить?

```
RxAlamofire.upload(multipartFormData: {multipartFormData in
    var i = 0
    for (title, image) in images {
        if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) {
            multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: title, fileName: "\(i).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        }
        i += 1
    }
}, to: url, method: .post, headers: headers).responseData()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока что пришлось прибегнуть к следующему костылю:

```
    func uploadImages(url: String, images: [String: UIImage]) -> ObservableApiResponse<ApiDefaultResponse> {
        var headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        ]
        if let token = token {
            headers["Authorization"] = token
        }
        return Observable<(HTTPURLResponse, Data)>.create { observer in
            AF.upload(multipartFormData: {multipartFormData in
                var i = 0
                for (title, image) in images {
                    if let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.9) {
                        multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: title, fileName: "\(i).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                    }
                    i += 1
                }
            }, to: Self.base_api_uri + url, method: .post, headers: headers).responseData { packedResponse in
                switch packedResponse.result {
                case let .success(result):
                    if let httpResponse = packedResponse.response {
                        observer.onNext((httpResponse, result))
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    } else {
                        observer.onError(RxAlamofireUnknownError)
                    }
                case let .failure(error):
                    observer.onError(error as Error)
                }
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
        .catchError {error in
            return .error(error)
        }
        .expectingObject(ofType: ApiDefaultResponse.self)
        .catchError {error in
            return .error(error)
        }
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
        .debug()
    }
```